# Battle between the Sun and the Moon forces?

Tags: myth-identification

I remember reading about a mythic battle between the forces of the moon and the sun. Not conflicts between Sun and Moon, but a war between armies of the sun and of the moon.

One of them, the sun possibly, won.

The myth might have been from India, Persia or Babylonia.

I am interested in the origin of the myth and if there are similar myths in other cultures?

**Edit**/ about Lucian's True History

I would have remembered non-sense fantasy elements, seas of milk, or flying acorns.... and even more so since i grew up in the Gibraltar strait

I think it was a foundation myth to establish the right to rule by a new dynasty. I am not certain that it was Indian and I may have mixed up two myths, but I seem to recall huge battles with elephants. The armies of the sun were like the new dynasty rightly conquering the "corrupt" old dynasty of the moon king or something like that.

- Further search; possibly the non-vedic kings in the Mahabharata war

Comment: Lucian's [True History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_History) perhaps?

Comment: No,  pretty sure in Asia: India or Middle-East, but thanks, i didn't know about the antique non-sensical SF "True History "

Comment: Well, Lucian was Assyrian, so that covers the Middle Eastern origin.

Answer (score 3):

I'm converting my comment to an answer, because a battle between the people of the Sun and the people of the Moon (over colonization of Venus) is the exact premise of [Lucian's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucian) [True History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_History). And yes, the armies of the Sun eventually win the battle.

The satire may be written in Greek, but Lucian was Assyrian and lived in [Samosata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samosata) (modern day Turkey, near the border with Syria). This might explain why you thought the myth was of Middle Eastern origin.

An English translation of the story by A.M. Harmon is available on Sacred-Texts: http://www.sacred-texts.com/cla/luc/true/index.htm

Comment: +1 for Lucian's True History, but i am certain this is not it.

Comment: @Reed Could you please update your question to explain why exactly  True History isn't the tale you are looking for? It fits all your requirements, even the vague one about a Middle Eastern origin.